# How to parse an array of multi-line json objects into separate elasticsearch documents using logstash?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a use case where I am going to be receiving a new file every hour that is picked up by filebeat and then sent to logstash. The file contains a number of json objects in an array split over multiple lines. I want to extract each object in the array and write them as individual documents to an elasticsearch index.

The json follows a structure similar to the below:

```
[
    {
        "Results": {
            "StartWeekSec": [
                2000,
                198000.0
            ],
            "ReportStartPeriod": "2019-01-15T07:00:00.000Z",
            "Constellation": "GPS",
            "ReferenceTime": [
                2000,
                31984.00
            ],
            "Status": 0
        },
        "ForecastResults": [
            {
                "Point": [
                    29.67,
                    -7.5
                ],
                "BestAccuracy": 10.98,
                "WorstAccuracy": 14.59              
            },
            {
                "Point": [
                    55.37,
                    54.1
                ],
                "BestAccuracy": 20,
                "WorstAccuracy": 13.99      
            }
        ]   
    },
    {
        "Results": {
            "StartWeekSec": [
                2000,
                198000.0
            ],
            "ReportStartPeriod": "2019-01-15T07:00:00.000Z",
            "Constellation": "GPS",
            "ReferenceTime": [
                2000,
                31984.00
            ],
            "Status": 0
        },
        "ForecastResults": [
            {
                "Point": [
                    29.67,
                    -7.5
                ],
                "BestAccuracy": 10.98,
                "WorstAccuracy": 14.59              
            },
            {
                "Point": [
                    55.37,
                    54.1
                ],
                "BestAccuracy": 20,
                "WorstAccuracy": 13.99      
            }
        ]   
    }   
]
```

As far as I know, the file should always be in this format, but the array `ForecastResults` can have any number of objects within it, it is not a defined amount.

So from the above example, I would expect there to be 2 elasticsearch documents created, both of which consisting of an object `Results` and an array of objects `ForecastResults`.

I am new to logstash so I'm not even 100% sure if this is possible to achieve, but I believe it should be. I have tried using the logstash [multiline plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) but I don't know what the pattern would be to identify each document?

So my main questions:

1. What is the regex I would need to extract each object from the array?
2. After I have extracted the object, how do I convert it into the desired format for my index mapping? Can this be done using grok?

I tried the following for my logstash.conf file, but it errored out saying I can't use the multiline codec with beats input, so I'm not sure what to do here. I know I can apply regex on the beats side, but I still don't know what that regex would look like.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => multiline {
      negate => false
      what => "previous"
      pattern => "{*}"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "events"
    ilm_enabled => "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use [JSON filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html).